# sam-compiled typescript Lambda function hangs when I add "new AWS.S3();"

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, sam

I am using the sam-generated hello-world typescript lambda demo.  It works fine,
until I include these lines:

```typescript
const notInvoked = () => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
};
```

Even if I don't call this "notInvoked" function, the lambda function hangs and times out without logging any of my console messages:

```typescript
import { SQSBatchItemFailure, SQSBatchResponse, SQSEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const notInvoked = () => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
};

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: SQSEvent): Promise<SQSBatchResponse> => {
  console.info(" === lambdaHandler === ");
  console.log("ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES\n" + JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2));
  console.info("EVENT\n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  const batchItemFailures: Array<SQSBatchItemFailure> = [];
  return {
    batchItemFailures
  };
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: this also happens when invoking locally.

Comment: did you checked your cloud watcher for any errors?

Comment: There are no log messages other than the generic START/END/RESULT entries, plus an entry that says it timed out.

Comment: `NOTE: You need to add "esModuleInterop": true to compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json. If not possible, use like import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'.

`

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, this seems to work for typescript:

```typescript
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3";
const s3 = new S3();
```

Maybe it has something to do with reducing the transpiled file size---not sure.

Comment: Miraculously, and confusingly... This worked - you're a life saver